# Открытые миры на основе звезд

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Я хочу открыть следующий мир на основе количества звезд.**
Я хочу знать, как рассчитать звезды в разных сценах. И как сделать пример.

Я получаю 2 звезды на первом уровне. Количество звезд +2. Сейчас я снова играю на первом уровне и собираю 3 звезды. Количество звезд +3: количество звезд достигло 5. Как определить количество звезд уровня ?

На втором уровне я получаю 1 звезду. Количество звезд +1. Сейчас я играю на втором уровне и собираю 2 звезды. Количество звезд +2. Количество звезд было 3.

Теперь я соединяю количество звезд на обоих уровнях и получаю 8, но на самом деле их должно быть 5.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне понять правильный момент.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


 public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour {


  public GameObject star1;
  public GameObject star2;
  public GameObject star3;




     protected string currentLevel;
     protected int worldIndex;
     protected int levelIndex;
     public static bool isLevelComplete ;


     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {

         isLevelComplete = false;
     //get the star images

     //disable the image component of all the star images
     star1.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
     star2.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
     star3.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;



     //save the current level name
     currentLevel = Application.loadedLevelName;

         ballon_1=0;
         scoreCoin = coin_num;
         coinscore = GetComponent<Text>();

         Panel_youwin.SetActive(false);
         Time.timeScale = 1f;

         Panel_youlose.SetActive(false);
         Time.timeScale = 1f;


     }

     void Update () {
         if (coinscore != null){

         coinscore.text = "Score " + scoreCoin;
         }

   // 3stars  if(ballon_1==astx_3&&Health.healthlife==3){
        star3.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
             UnlockLevels(3);
         Panel_youwin.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0f;
     }

  // 2stars    if(ballon_1==astx_2&&Health.healthlife==2){
         star2.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
         UnlockLevels(2);
         Panel_youwin.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0f;    
     }

 // 1stars    if(ballon_1==astx_1&&Health.healthlife==1){
         star1.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
         UnlockLevels(1);
         Panel_youwin.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0f;
     }

     if(Health.healthlife <= 0){
         Panel_youlose.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0f;

         }    
     }
      protected void  UnlockLevels (int stars){

   //set the playerprefs value of next level to 1 to unlock
   //also set the playerprefs value of stars to display them on the World levels menu
   for(int i = 0; i < LockLevel.worlds; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < LockLevel.levels; j++){               
     if(currentLevel == "Level"+(i+1).ToString() +"." +j.ToString()){
      worldIndex  = (i+1);
      levelIndex  = (j+1);
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level"+worldIndex.ToString() +":" +levelIndex.ToString(),1);
      //check if the current stars value is less than the new value
      if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level"+worldIndex.ToString() +":" +j.ToString()+"stars")< stars)
       //overwrite the stars value with the new value obtained
       PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level"+worldIndex.ToString() +":" +j.ToString()+"stars",stars);
     }
    }
   }

  }


  }
```

Comment: Что такое "уровень справа", который возник из ниоткуда?

Comment: Как определить количество звезд уровня

Comment: how to do it,,,,

Comment: Чтобы не присваивать звезды повторно, для каждого уровня надо их хранить. Про PlayerPrefs почитайте.

Comment: я могу их хранить, но как их сложить

Comment: Элдар совершенно не  понятно чего вы хотите. Код не прокомментировал. Очень не удобочитаемо. Возможно стоит разбить его на более атомарные задачи так сказать сам вопрос разобрать на более атомарный. _Могу предположить что не получается сбросить счётчик к примеру я начал заново но дошёл до третьего уровня снова , и теперь у меня не три звезды а шесть из за этого очень сильно страдает механика игры ??_  Распишите пожалуйста вопрос поподробней, с пониманием планов и целей

Comment: Спосибо, уже решил